У меня очень часто такая ошибка AttributeError: 'Dispatcher' object has no attribute 'message_handler'
вот тут ошибка AttributeError: 'Dispatcher' object has no attribute 'message_handler'.
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types, F
from aiogram.types import Message
from aiogram.exceptions import TelegramBadRequest
import asyncio
from aiogram.filters import Command, CommandStart
import random
import time
import psutil
import pytube
import os
import re
import logging

startTime = time.time()

bot = Bot("6475302931:AAF8e5rDO6JYQCINJu7zXFbQukXbcgwd2mk")
dp = Dispatcher()

def getUptime():
    """
    Returns the number of seconds since the program started.
    """
    return time.time() - startTime

@dp.message(F.text.lower().in_(["фота"]))
async def send_photo(message: Message):
    photo = "https://i.ibb.co/NKSkGv1/1.jpg"
    await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo, caption="fhfhfhfhfhffh")

@dp.message(F.text.lower().in_(["тест"]))
async def randim(message: Message):
    greetings(Message)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
@dp.message_handler(commands=['download'])
async def download_video(message: types.Message):
    try:
        command, link = message.get_full_command().split(maxsplit=1)
        if not link:
            await message.reply("Please provide a TikTok video link.")
            return
        file_name = "video.mp4"  # default file name
        if len(link.split()) > 1:
            link, file_name = link.split(maxsplit=1)
        save_path = f"downloads/{file_name}"
        if await download_tiktok_video(link, save_path):
            await message.reply("Video downloaded successfully.")
            with open(save_path, 'rb') as video:
                await message.reply_video(video)
            os.remove(save_path)  # Delete the file after sending
        else:
            await message.reply("Failed to download the video.")
    except ValueError:
        await message.reply("Invalid command format. Please use /download {link} {filename}")


@dp.message(F.text.lower().in_(["ага"]))
async def greetings(message: Message):
    nick1_result = message.from_user.username
    nick2_result = message.reply_to_message.from_user.username
    radom = random.randint(1, 2)
    if radom == 1:
        photo = "https://i.ibb.co/NKSkGv1/1.jpg"
        await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo, caption=f"@{nick1_result} ага ага @{nick2_result}")
    elif radom == 2:
        photo = "https://i.ibb.co/VBNw2X0/2.jpg"
        await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo, caption=f"@{nick1_result} ага ага  @{nick2_result}")


@dp.message(F.text.lower().in_(["дебаг"]))
async def debug(message: Message):
    uptime = getUptime()
    ram = psutil.virtual_memory()[3]/1000000000
    await message.reply(f"Аптайм: {uptime}\nram: {ram}")

# Скачивалки для ют и тт

async def handle_text(message: types.Message):
    text = message.text
    if text.startswith('https://www.youtube.com/'):
        yt = text
        await message.reply(f"Скачивание видео с Ютуба начинается")
    url = f"{yt}"
    yt = pytube.YouTube(url)
    video = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
    video.download()
    original_filename = video.filename
    new_filename = "1"
    os.rename(original_filename, new_filename)




async def main():
    await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

В почти каждом @dp.message_handler() ошибка.
пробовал много чего, просто искал может одну букву ошибся, весь интернет перерыл, ничего
